# How to force VC++ 2013 compiler to assume 16b alignment in own allocator?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-alignment

Hello I run into one serious problem. I'am writing own allocator for my classes. Allocator supports memory alignment. Problem is that i'am using SSE so some structures in my code are __declspec(align(16)). Compilator is able to figure this out and warn me about this alignment although i have globally overidden new and delete. Warnings are ok, i can live with them but when i used my allocator an structure with alignment compiler refused to compile code with error:

```
error C2719: '<args_0>': formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned
```

My alignment should be correct using this calculation:

```
(sizeof(DataType)+MemAlignment-1)) & ~(MemAlignment-1)
```

I also checked memory adresses and it is really creating memory pointers ending with 0 so with 16-bit alignment.

This is function that should return pointer to "new" memory and throwing compilation error:

```
//! Will return pointer to memory location that is free.
template<typename... Args>
DataType *RequestObj(Args... args)
{
    if(_unusedMemTop <= 0)
        addPool();
    DataType *tmp = _unusedMem[_unusedMemTop--];
    return tmp;
}
```

Is there any possibility how to tell VC++ compiler that memory is aligned? For example something like __assume_aligned() in gcc or __restrict in VC++ where i'am giving "promise" about pointer usage?

Thank you so much for your help.

**RESOLVED:**
Error was related to first param to templated function not to whole templated class as i thought before. Huge facepalm... Thank you guys so much...

**Fixed line:**

```
DataType *RequestObj(const Args&... args)
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't complain about the heap, but the stack. Apparently, you have a function call like `f(x)` where `x` is of an overaligned type. The compiler can't guarantee that it will be properly aligned when pushed on the stack.

Comment: Read the error.  It says, "parameter"  which is something passed to a function.  IE: it is being copied onto the stack with default alignment.  You should pass it as a const ref.  And if your ussing SSE you should probably use compiler intrinsic's, so that it gets passed in an actual SSE register - otherwise your wasting your time using SSE.